# Get lock in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My team use TortoiseSVN to code version control. Sometimes, someone use 'get lock' option. Is it possible to see locks got in solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html#tsvn-dug-locking-status:

To see what locks you and others hold, you can use TortoiseSVN → Check for Modifications.... Locally held lock tokens show up immediately. To check for locks held by others (and to see if any of your locks are broken or stolen) you need to click on Check Repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server hosting your SVN, and you can open terminal or shell, you can type the following command:

```
svnadmin lslocks /path/to/repo
```

This will give you the information you are seeking, and you also have additional commands:

```
mike$ svnadmin help
general usage: svnadmin SUBCOMMAND REPOS_PATH  [ARGS & OPTIONS ...]
Type 'svnadmin help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Type 'svnadmin --version' to see the program version and FS modules.

Available subcommands:
   crashtest
   create
   deltify
   dump
   help (?, h)
   hotcopy
   list-dblogs
   list-unused-dblogs
   load
   lslocks
   lstxns
   pack
   recover
   rmlocks
   rmtxns
   setlog
   setrevprop
   setuuid
   upgrade
   verify
```